# Solving $1 - e^{-2\lambda} = 2e^{-4\lambda}$ for $\lambda$

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-distributions, exponential-function, roots

The problem seems simple:

Let X be an exponential random variable such that $P(X \le 2) = 2P(X > 4)$.
Find the variance of X.

Easy, right?
$
P(x \le 2) = 1 - e^{-2\lambda} $
and
$ P(x > 4) = e^{-4\lambda} $

Assuming that is right, which, it's possible that it is not...

I can't find any way to solve
$$  1 - e^{-2\lambda} = 2e^{-4\lambda} $$ for $\lambda$.

I am rusty on my Exponential and logarithmic function solving, but it seems unsolvable.

I have tried taking $ln$ of both sides.  Then what do you do with $\ln(1 - e^{-2\lambda})$?

I have tried rewriting 1 as $e^{0}$ but that didn't get me any further.

I know the variance is $\frac{4}{(\ln 2) ^2}$ which means $\lambda = \frac {\ln 2} {2}$. And that checks out with the equation above ($.5 = .5$).  But how?

Thank you!

Comment: Make the substitution $u = e^{-2\lambda}$, and solve the resulting quadratic equation.  Once you have values for $u$, convert them back in to $\lambda$.  _Hint:_ there's only one solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like a quadratic equation with respect to $e^{-2\lambda}$. The only positive solution of $1-x=2x^2$ is $\frac12$, so $e^{-2\lambda}=\frac12$, which gives the desired answer.

Comment: Wow! I don't think I have ever solved a quadratic with respect to a variable in an exponent position.  Another trick in the arsenal. TYVM.

Comment: You're welcome.